# Concatenate in a dplyr filter

Tags: r, dplyr, concatenation, stringr

There must be a lapse in my understanding of applying concatenations. For some reason this command works

```
vec <- as.matrix(df %>%filter(Sex == "male" & !str_detect(Title, "Rev.")) %>% select(PassengerId))
```

But when I run a similar command to include multiple possible titles it doesn't work:

```
miss.weirdo_vec <- as.matrix(weirdos %>%filter(Sex == "female" & str_detect(Title, c("Ms"|"Mlle"|"Mme"|"Dona"))) select(PassengerId))
```

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  filter(Sex == "female" & str_detect(Title, c("Ms"|"Mlle"|"Mme"|"Dona")))
  select"

The goal of this is to create a matrix of passenger Id's who are female and have any of the four concatenated titles. Any help on getting the right code would be great, but moreover, an explanation as to why this isn't working would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. It is always very appreciated to have some sample data to create a reproducible error.

Comment: `c("Ms"|"Mlle"|"Mme"|"Dona")` obviously doesn't work because you concatenate with the symbol `,` (comma) and not '|'.  I also guess that you would need to specify your filter with `%in% c(...)` in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you want this, but I can't verify without knowing your dataset:

```
miss.weirdo_vec <- as.matrix(weirdos %>%
                               filter(Sex == "female",
                                      Title %in% c("Ms","Mlle","Mme","Dona")) %>%
                               select(PassengerId))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I was mistakenly using an & operator instead of , for multiple dplyr::filter parameters. Thanks so much.